# JCIFS + Kerberos + Java 7

Tags: java-7, kerberos, jcifs

I am using JCIFS with Kerberos module library (jcifs-krb5-1.3.17) in a Java application that authenticates in a Windows KDC Server and after that try to access a shared folder on network using the Kerberos ticket retrieved.

The app that I'm using is the same that is present in JCIFS website example (KerberosAuthExample.java).

When using JDK1.6, it works perfectly.

However, when I tried using JDK1.7 it returned the following exception:

**jcifs.smb.SmbAuthentication: Access is denied.**

I've already tried executing as a PrivilegedAction using the subject retrieved from authentication, but it returns the same result.

Is somebody facing the same problem?

Can you please help me?

Thanks in advance,

Stuchi

Answer (score 0):

The way we read Kerberos keytab path is different in jdk7. below is the code for reading keytab, if we are using spring security kerberos extension.

```
String keyTabPath = this.keyTabLocation.getURL().toExternalForm();

if (runtimeVersion.startsWith("1.7")) 
{   
        if (keyTabPath.startsWith("file:")) 
        {
            keyTabPath = keyTabPath.substring(5);
        }
}
```

For code details, read [SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator:afterPropertiesSet()](http://git.springsource.org/spring-security/se-security/blobs/386503d2ed7efd48f196081bd2d23497bfbb488a/spring-security-kerberos/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/extensions/kerberos/SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator.java)

JCIFS project is not active (last release in 2011) and i am not sure either it's based on JAAS standard (javax.security.auth).

Better try spring security kerberos extenstion. For more details on spring security kerberos , read chapter-12 of [Spring Security3-authored by Peter Mularien](http://www.zenisoft.cn/calibre/browse/book/703).

Comment: Hello,

Where can I put this in my code?
You can find my code example below:

http://pastebin.com/Z1V38fL9

Thanks again,